# How to query this data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores information about packets. A packet may either an item or another packet (which can contain just items).
So, at the max, the items are '2' level down.

I need to find out the items and their respective 'main' packets.

for example,

this is the table

```
 | Packet | Item |
 |   1    |  2   |
 |   1    |  3   |
 |   2    |  4   |
 |   2    |  5   |
```

I'm trying to list the items along with their parents (if they are not contained in any packet themselves or the packet in which the packet containing them is present)

That is, for this test data, result set should be

```
| Packet | Item |
|   1    |  3   |
|   1    |  4   |
|   1    |  5   |
```

The query I'm using is this

```
select a.packet, b.item from test a, test b where a.item = b.packet
union
select packet, item from test where packet not in (select item from test) and item not in (select packet from test);
```

It works but is there a better way to do this?
Here's the fiddle for this scenario :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbf65/1
Thanks!

Comment: How is it possible to become {2, 4} and  {2, 5} into {1, 4} and {1, 5}?

Comment: Because 4 and 5 are items that are contained in packet '2', which itself is contained in packet '1'.
I need to track items and their top level packets.

Comment: As far i understand, there's no relationship between packets...

Answer (score 4):

You need to read this https://web.archive.org/web/20100924051755/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html?

It explains how to build hierarchy and how to query it. There is two different way to store it and both have pros and cons.

The first method is simpler but won't scale.
The second method need 2 extra columns and complicated queries but make it more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your meaning correctly, try

```
SELECT t1.packet AS packet,
IFNULL(t2.item, t1.item) AS item,
t2.item
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.item = t2.packet
HAVING t2.item IS NULL
```

It works but it's messy. Please see @A.D. 's comment about having a better design!